# Use a C struct in C++/CLI, calling conventions issue

Tags: c, c++-cli, calling-convention

I'm using [lib_usb](http://www.libusb.org/) in my C++/CLI project, and I need to use it's functions `usb_get_busses` and some others in my managed C++/CLI code.

Using a managed `AutoPtr` to create the `usb_bus` struct as follows:

`AutoPtr<struct usb_bus> bus;`

now I need to call the `usb_get_busses` function, however the linker seems to be unhappy as to the calling conventions.  The CLR uses the clrcall calling convention, and obviously C using `__cdecl`.

`usb_bus* usb_get_busses(void)` <--- the signature of the C function.

Now how do I make myself able to use the `lib_usb` in C++/CLI?  Do I have to create a C++/CLI wrapper or something?

The linker spits out this message:

> error LNK2031: unable to generate p/invoke for "extern "C" struct
>   usb_bus * __clrcall usb_get_busses(void)"
>   (?usb_get_busses@@$$J0YMPAUusb_bus@@XZ); calling convention missing in
>   metadata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not specified with `__cdecl` at all. Look at the linker error- it clearly states `__clrcall`. Try explicitly specifying it with `__cdecl`.

Comment: FYI - I did mean that C's calling convention is `__cdecl` and not that my particular c function is already declared with `__cdecl` explicitly.